# cannot read array after GET and setState, even though its there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

The GET request which pulls all orders made by a certain user. Strange setup but it does pull the data correctly.

```
    var all = [];
    axios.get('/api/orders/' + this.props.user.name)
    .then(function (res) {
        res.data.forEach(e => {
            e.orders.forEach(eachOrder => {
                 all.push (
                    eachOrder
                )
            })  
        })
        console.log('this be all: ', all);
    })
    this.setState({
        orders : all
    });
```

eachOrder does print the orders (for each order):

`{type: "Pizza", extraType: "na", extraInfo: "na", date: "", quantity: "1", …}`

this be all console.log :

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {type: "Pizza", extraType: "na", extraInfo: "na", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
1: {type: "na", extraType: "Can", extraInfo: "Diet Coke", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
2: {type: "na", extraType: "Can", extraInfo: "Diet Coke", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
3: {type: "na", extraType: "1 Pound", extraInfo: "Honey Garlic", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
4: {type: "na", extraType: "1 Pound", extraInfo: "Honey Garlic", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Perfect, just what I expected. I set the state's orders to all..but orders seem to be very strange?

```
if (this.state.orders !== null) {
  console.log('lets see the order: ', this.state.orders)
}
```

lets see the order .. :

```
[]
0: {type: "Pizza", extraType: "na", extraInfo: "na", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
1: {type: "na", extraType: "Can", extraInfo: "Diet Coke", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
2: {type: "na", extraType: "Can", extraInfo: "Diet Coke", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
3: {type: "na", extraType: "1 Pound", extraInfo: "Honey Garlic", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
4: {type: "na", extraType: "1 Pound", extraInfo: "Honey Garlic", date: "", quantity: "1", …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I can't check the `.length` of the order, I can't `map` or `forEach`, nothing. I can't check elements within the array ether.

Any idea what is going on with it?

Comment: `this.setState({ orders : all  });` should be inside then block

Comment: that can't be done. If I setState within the block (after the console.log) I get this error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `setState` within the callback of your http async request. You are getting the promise rejection error because your `this` reference is being re-directed  to the `function(res) {}`.

This happens a lot when you use the `function` keyword for callback instead of the ES6 arrow function (also the best practice in writing React component methods)

Here's what you can do, replace `function() {}` with `() => {}`:

```
var all = [];
axios.get('/api/orders/' + this.props.user.name)
.then((res) => {   //change function to arrow function
    res.data.forEach(e => {
        e.orders.forEach(eachOrder => {
             all.push (
                eachOrder
            )
        })  
    })
    this.setState({
        orders : all
    });
    console.log('this be all: ', all);
})
```

OR, if you need or want to continue to use the `function` keyword as callback, you can turn your component method into an arrow function to bind the reference of `this` to the component

```
mySexyMethod = () => {
    var all = [];
    axios.get('/api/orders/' + this.props.user.name)
    .then(function (res) {
        res.data.forEach(e => {
            e.orders.forEach(eachOrder => {
                 all.push (
                    eachOrder
                )
            })  
        })
        this.setState({
          orders : all
        });
        console.log('this be all: ', all);
    })
}
```

But whichever solution you decide to take, the first and most important part of the problem is with your `setState` not being in the callback of your async request, simply move that into the block will make it work.

Comment: Excellent answer and detail, it helped. I had no idea that would cause an issue.

Comment: @RobertOchinski glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `setState` is being run before the fetch call completes, since it's outside of the `then` block. Also to access `this` inside the `then` block, you need to make your axios callback function an arrow function:

`.then((res) => {`

It could just look like this:

```
axios.get('/api/orders/' + this.props.user.name)
.then((res) => {
  const orders = res.data.reduce((acc, e) => {
    return [...acc, ...e.orders]
  }, [])
  this.setState({orders})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function for the `then` block and move the `setState` inside. That should do.

Have a look at this doc, it might help https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Atleast this is working for men here https://github.com/mustafamamun/Test/blob/master/UI/src/App.js

```
axios.get('/api/orders/' + this.props.user.name)
.then(res=> {
    res.data.forEach(e => {
        e.orders.forEach(eachOrder => {
             all.push (
                eachOrder
            )
        })  
    })
    console.log('this be all: ', all);
    this.setState({
      orders : all
    });
})
```